# d3: assigning 2 filters to a node and having the node disappear when one filter is "de-selected"

Tags: javascript, d3.js, filter, nodes

So I'm working on creating a network with `d3`.

I don't know how to assign 2 filters to a node because it requires me to click both filters for the node to disappear - I want it to disappear even when 1 node is clicked (only show up when both are clicked).

For example:

```
var links = [{source: "Andrea", target: "London", type: "Nurse", group: "1"},{source: "Andrea", target: "London", type: "Cardiologist", group: "1"},];
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nkp13/W5WKq/3/

So she should filter when Nurse and Cardiologist are un-checked

I want it so that when I un-check "Nurse" OR "Cardiologist", she disappears but as of right now I have to un-check both "Nurse" AND "Cardiologist" for her to disappear.

Any guidance or suggestions on this would really help and be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You could make `type` a list and have both "nurse" and "cardiologist" in the list for that node.

Comment: If I write it like this:

var links = [{source: "Andrea", target: "London", type: "Nurse", type:"Cardiologist", group: "1"},];

The second type (so type: "Cardiologist") ends up filtering and Nurse does not..

Thank you for your suggestion though, and if you have anymore (or I misunderstood you) please let me know!

Comment: Something like `type: ["Nurse", "Cardiologist"]`. You would also need to adapt the rest of your code to work with lists.